# Is every decreasing/increasing sequence (with n being a natural number) bounded from above/below?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Take a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which is decreasing. By the definition of being bounded from above, which is "If a sequence is bounded from above,

$\exists K\in\mathbb{R}: a_n\leq K, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$",

any decreasing sequence would should be bounded from above by $a_1$, because $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so $n=1,2,3,4,...,n$. Is this true?

Comment: Everything up to "above by $a_1$" is correct, but what comes after 'because' is very strange.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. To satisfy my curiosity: why did you ask this? And to nitpick: you should write $n=1,2,\ldots$. Without the $n$ in the end. Two reasons for that 1) you cannot use $n$ in two roles, 2) if you write the last index that means that your sequence is finite - with exactly $n$ members.

Comment: @GitGud, the part after 'because' is there because if n is not in the natural numbers then an increasing sequence would not be bounded from below.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. And if $a_n$ is increasing it is bounded from below, since  then $a_n\ge a_1$.